# Cheat engine address to Intptr?

Tags: c#, cheat-engine

I used cheat engine to search for a string in 'Notepad++'.
Then I got '1897E119A50' address that contain the string.
I want to read 100 bytes of strings starting from that address.

However ProcessMemory.ReadByteArray function will only accept IntPtr address.
How do I convert the cheat engine address to IntPtr?

```
ProcessMemory p3 = new ProcessMemory("Notepad++");
var b2 = p3.ReadByteArray((IntPtr)0x1897E119A50, 100); //<-I get 'Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow'
var str = getStringFromBytes(b2);
```

Comment: Either open the file and search it in the stream  or use the editor to jump to it

Comment: I have to read it from the memory since the strings are only in memory. Notepad++ is only an example in this case.

Comment: Is this program running in 32-bit mode?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to learn but I'm stuck here for days. I get System.OverflowException: 'Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.' if I try to convert the address to intptr.

Comment: It's not going to work like that, change the platform target to x64

Comment: Oh, I changed the platform target to x64 and I'm not getting Error! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr.op_explicit?view=net-8.0#system-intptr-op-explicit(system-int64)-system-intptr), shall we?

> ### Exceptions
>
> `OverflowException`
>
> In a 32-bit process, value is too large to represent as an IntPtr.

Well, there you have it. `IntPtr` has the size of a pointer, so its maximum size depends on whether you're building a 32 bit or 64 bit application. In a 32 bit process, it's also 32 bits, so it cannot hold anything larger than `uint.MaxValue`. There's just not enough bytes in there.

`0x1897E119A50` is too big for it (it's a `long`), so you'll have to make the switch by targeting x64.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. It took me whole day. : )